# Переключение блоков при клике на кнопку

Tags: jquery

Необходимо совместить кнопки с блоками контента, нужно чтобы при нажатии на 1 кнопку отображались все блоки, на 2 кнопку - 1 и 2 блок, на 3 кнопку - 2, 3, 4 блоки на 4 кнопку - 1, 3 блоки

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".title").click(function(e) {
    $(".title").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
.button {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.title{
    background-color:  #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color:  #8c8c8c;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.projectGroup {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.project {
    background-color: #fbfaf8;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 30%;
    display: none;
}
.title.active {
    background-color:  #998675;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #998675;
}
.project.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<aside class="portfolio">
    <div class="button">
        <input type="button"  class="title all active" value="all">
        <input type="button"  class="title design" value="web design">
        <input type="button"  class="title mobile" value="mobile app">
        <input type="button"  class="title illustration" value="illustration">
        <input type="button"  class="title photography" value="photography">
    </div>
    <!--Projects-->
    <div class="projectGroup portfolio-wrap">

        <!--Projects 1-->
        <div class="project ">
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aut consectetur, consequuntur debitis distinctio dolorem enim, error et eum ex fuga minima natus obcaecati perferendis provident quia reiciendis vero voluptatibus.</p>
               <h5>Photography, Nature</h5>
        </div>

        <!--Projects 2-->
        <div class="project ">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aut consectetur, consequuntur debitis distinctio dolorem enim, error et eum ex fuga minima natus obcaecati perferendis provident quia reiciendis vero voluptatibus.</p>
            <h5>Photography, Nature</h5>
        </div>

        <!--Projects 3-->
        <div class="project ">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aut consectetur, consequuntur debitis distinctio dolorem enim, error et eum ex fuga minima natus obcaecati perferendis provident quia reiciendis vero voluptatibus.</p>
            <h5>Photography, Nature</h5>
        </div>

        <!--Projects 4-->
        <div class="project ">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aut consectetur, consequuntur debitis distinctio dolorem enim, error et eum ex fuga minima natus obcaecati perferendis provident quia reiciendis vero voluptatibus.</p>
            <h5>Photography, Nature</h5>
        </div>

        <!--Projects 5-->
        <div class="project ">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aut consectetur, consequuntur debitis distinctio dolorem enim, error et eum ex fuga minima natus obcaecati perferendis provident quia reiciendis vero voluptatibus.</p>
            <h5>Photography, Nature</h5>
        </div>

        <!--Projects 6-->
        <div class="project ">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aut consectetur, consequuntur debitis distinctio dolorem enim, error et eum ex fuga minima natus obcaecati perferendis provident quia reiciendis vero voluptatibus.</p>
            <h5>Photography, Nature</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Почему бы не взять готовый фильтр ? [Например](http://yiotis.net/filterizr/) или например [посмотреть тут](http://www.bestjquery.com/demo/jquery-portfolio-gallery-plugin/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, добавить кнопкам атрибут `data-target` с названием нужного класса (`design`, `mobile`, и т.д.), а блокам `.project` соответствующие классы:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".title").click(function(e) {
    $(".title").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if ($(this).data('target') == 'all') {
      $('.project').addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.project.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.project.' + $(this).data('target')).addClass('active');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.button {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.title{
    background-color:  #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color:  #8c8c8c;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.projectGroup {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.project {
    background-color: #fbfaf8;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 30%;
    display: none;
}
.title.active {
    background-color:  #998675;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #998675;
}
.project.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<aside class="portfolio">
    <div class="button">
        <input type="button" class="title all active" value="all" data-target="all">
        <input type="button" class="title design" value="web design" data-target="design">
        <input type="button" class="title mobile" value="mobile app" data-target="mobile">
        <input type="button" class="title illustration" value="illustration" data-target="illustration">
        <input type="button"  class="title photography" value="photography" data-target="photography">
    </div>
    <!--Projects-->
    <div class="projectGroup portfolio-wrap">

        <!--Projects 1-->
        <div class="project design illustration">
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aut consectetur, consequuntur debitis distinctio dolorem enim, error et eum ex fuga minima natus obcaecati perferendis provident quia reiciendis vero voluptatibus.</p>
               <h5>Photography, Nature</h5>
        </div>

        <!--Projects 2-->
        <div class="project design mobile">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aut consectetur, consequuntur debitis distinctio dolorem enim, error et eum ex fuga minima natus obcaecati perferendis provident quia reiciendis vero voluptatibus.</p>
            <h5>Photography, Nature</h5>
        </div>

        <!--Projects 3-->
        <div class="project mobile illustration">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aut consectetur, consequuntur debitis distinctio dolorem enim, error et eum ex fuga minima natus obcaecati perferendis provident quia reiciendis vero voluptatibus.</p>
            <h5>Photography, Nature</h5>
        </div>

        <!--Projects 4-->
        <div class="project mobile">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aut consectetur, consequuntur debitis distinctio dolorem enim, error et eum ex fuga minima natus obcaecati perferendis provident quia reiciendis vero voluptatibus.</p>
            <h5>Photography, Nature</h5>
        </div>

        <!--Projects 5-->
        <div class="project ">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aut consectetur, consequuntur debitis distinctio dolorem enim, error et eum ex fuga minima natus obcaecati perferendis provident quia reiciendis vero voluptatibus.</p>
            <h5>Photography, Nature</h5>
        </div>

        <!--Projects 6-->
        <div class="project ">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aut consectetur, consequuntur debitis distinctio dolorem enim, error et eum ex fuga minima natus obcaecati perferendis provident quia reiciendis vero voluptatibus.</p>
            <h5>Photography, Nature</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь